# How to get the history of SSH connections with time?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, gnome-terminal

How to get the history of the ssh connection with the time, like at what time the machine accessed via ssh and by who in Linux/Unix using terminal command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command, in a terminal window, `journalctl /usr/sbin/sshd` will show you log messages like (I am user `walt`, and just did a `ssh localhost`):

```
Feb 04 09:33:54 bat sshd[17129]: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/walt is already mounted
Feb 04 09:33:54 bat sshd[17129]: Accepted password for walt from 127.0.0.1 port 52642 ssh2
Feb 04 09:33:54 bat sshd[17129]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user walt by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pinky`
`apt install pinky`
The use is straightforward - just execute 
`pinky` in terminal.

Comment: Thanks @Gravemind. Using `pinky` command I was able to get short history (say 5 instance). Using the command mentioned by waltinator I was able to get ssh history for a month.

Comment: NP ;) Pinky got a lot of options. You can see them via man pinky